# Git не хочет подключаться: git status fatal: Not a git repository

Tags: git, репозиторий

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может причина появления данного сообщения или лучше увидеть воочию ?

> $ git status fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent
>   directories): .git

Answer (score 21):

Перед началом использования репозитория вы должны его инициализировать командой `git init`. Быстро научиться работать с Git поможет этот интерактивный курс: http://try.github.io/.

Либо перейти в каталог (папку, директорию), содержащий ранее созданный репозиторий с помощью команды `cd`.

```
cd /var/www/html/
```

Признаком такой папки (каталога, директории) является наличие папки .git (с точкой в начале, т.е. скрытой) внутри.
Проверить (убедиться в) её наличие можно, просмотрев содержимое директории (каталога, папки) с помощью команды `ls` с ключом (опцией) `-a` или `-A`

```
ls -a
.  ..  .git  index.nginx-debian.html

ls -A
.git  index.nginx-debian.html
```

Параметр `-l` (long listing format) позволяет убедиться, что `.git` - это именно директория (буква `d` в начале свойств вместо знака `-` если бы `.git` был файлом)

```
ls -lA
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Apr 24 01:58 .git
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  430 Apr 20 08:53 index.nginx-debian.html
```

В зависимости от используемой вами командной оболочки (shell) вывод команды ls или автодополнение пути (вызываемое клавишей Tab) может снабжать каталоги слешем в конце при выводе их списка

```
.git/
```

Для использования git в повседневной работе удобно модифицировать приглашение к вводу команд (promt) добавлением в него указания на использование системы контроля версий, выбранной ветке, коммите и статусе рабочей директории,
как описано, например в

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883416/adding-git-branch-on-the-bash-command-prompt

Comment: и еще [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-git)

Comment: или на русском https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1

Comment: @ГерманБорисов книга не столь интерактивна, но тоже неплохо :)

Comment: @AlexChermenin в книге раз в двадцать больше знаний, чем в очень базовом курсе на codecademy )

Comment: @NickVolynkin не спорю. с помощью курса можно быстро получить базовые знания и начать работать. а с помощью книг в дальнейшем эти знания расширять.

Comment: @AlexChermenin согласен, что стартовать легче с курса.

Answer (score 10):

У вас текущая директория не под гитом. Чтобы было под гитом, необходимо либо выполнить

```
git clone <url>
```

либо

```
git init
```

Answer (score 1):

Встретил аналогичную ошибку после `git clone <url>`. Ругался правильно, т.к. после клонирования надо было перейти в каталог созданный при клонировании командой `cd <dir>`.

Далее `git status` покажет изменения, если они есть.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно указать директорию в которой есть существующий проект:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory С:/GitHub/ПапкаПроэкта
```